# Кэширование Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, кэширование

Всем привет.Появилось несколько вопросов по работе с кэшем в Laravel:

1 - Правильно ли я понимаю, что, к примеру, следующий код:

```
$product = Cache::remember('product'.$productId, 60, function () {
   return Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Запомнит конкретный продукт на 60 минут и не будет дергать таблицу `products` в течение 60 минут? (Потом этот кэш попросту обновится?) Правильно ли сделана конкатенация для получения правильного ключа `'product'.$productId`?

2 - насколько правильным будет выполнение следующих действий: у меня есть таблица `user_bonuses`, из которой мне нужно получать сумму полученных бонусов за вычитанием потраченных бонусов. Правильным ли будет кэширование данного элемента? Т.е. для каждого пользователя (для отображения в личном кабинете) есть свой баланс бонусов, который выполнен на основе нормализации БД - бонусы считаются отдельно.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно, но если в течении этих 60 минут он обратится к кешу и не найдет данных то сработает функция обратного вызова и перезапишет кеш. Конкатенация сделана синтаксически верно а по логике я не знаю, лучше добавить разделитель "_" к стати чтоб передать в функцию $id тебе нужно дописать use.

```
$product = Cache::remember('product'.$productId, 60, function () use ($id){
   return Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
});`
```

2. Засовывай в кеш что не очень часто меняется в данном случае бонусы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!)